# Qmake error : Unknown module(s) in QT: charts

Tags: c++, qt

Am getting the error when I *Run qmake* on my application

```
Unknown module(s) in QT: charts
```

I am using Qt Creator 4.8 (Enterprise) and Qt library 5.12 on Windows 7.

My *.pro* file has the following line:

```
QT += core gui charts
```

In my source file I include *ChartView* like this:

```
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
...
```

However, when I run one of the demo examples that ships with QT and have a similar include, the program compiles and runs fine.
The example am running is found here:

```
..Qt5.12.0\Examples\Qt-5.12.0\charts\donutchart
```

What am I missing in my application?

Regards,

Paul

Comment: When you installed Qt did you enable the option to install Qt Charts?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this I had to re-install the Qt library. Actually I decided to upgrade to Qt 5.13.2, now the program compiles and runs well.

Things to note:

The MaintenanceTool does not work very well, I think it is still work-in-progress. I managed to remove QtCharts module for Qt 5.12 using the tool, however, when I tried to use it to re-install the module, the Maintenance tool could not find the QtCharts library. I was eventually forced to remove the entire 5.12.0 library and install 5.13.2. The program now compiles well.